# how do i use splitstring function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

I have created this javascript function

```
  function fillGaps()
{
var selectElement = document.snowForm.snoww;
var values = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
var words[] = values.split(" ");
var firstWord = words[0];
var secondWord = words[1];
var thirdWord = words[2];

alert(values);



document.snowForm.last.value = firstWord;
document.snowForm.first.value = secondWord;
document.snowForm.phone.value = thirdWord;
}
```

So now, please let me explain few things. I have a form which name is snowForm. In this form i have a select element which its options will always be aparted from strings, first name - last name - phone number.

```
<option value="Malkovic">John Malkovic 1514 4124</option>
<option value="Malkovic">Chris Davidson 6234 2634</option>
<option value="Malkovic">Bill Parker 3134 2124</option>
```

etc..

So lets say i pick one of these options and onchange i want my function to fill these 3 input areas

```
<input type="text" name="last"/>
<input type="text" name="first"/>
<input type="text" name="phone"/>
```

with the 3 words that my function split.

My problem is that i think that it should work correctly but it actually does not do anything.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance, Telis.

Comment: `var words[] = values.split(" ");` not sure what that is

Comment: Does it correctly alert the values? This is a pretty old style for access DOM nodes (`document.formName.inputName`), I would give your elements an `id` and target them like `document.getElementById('last').value = secondWord;`

Comment: @epascarello: that looks like Java syntax to me; Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid JavaScript

```
var words[] = values.split(" ");
```

it should be

```
var words = values.split(" ");
```

Learn to use your debugger, there should be error messages in the console. Also there are tools like JSLInt or JSHint that can point out these syntax errors.

Now option does not have innerHTML

```
var values = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

it has text

```
var values = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;
```